# Trying to use Applescript variable in curl command inside do shell script for phone calls

Tags: shell, applescript

i have no clue at all but i'm quite desperated... i try to use the follow apple skript establishing a call on my snom desktop phone. when i put the link directly in the browser it works fine. but there seem to be a mistake in the skript - as nothing is happening when i use it in the software...

would be so great if somebody has the answer...

```
set tel to "xxx"
set telOhneSpace to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of tel & " | sed -e 's/ //g'"
set theScript to "curl
http://admin:PASSWORD@1XX.XXX.XXX.XX:XXXX/command.htm?number=" & telOhneSpace
do shell script theScript
   delay 1.0
   tell application "System Events"
      key code 36
   end tell
```

if i put this into my browser:

`http://admin:PASSWORD@1XX.XXX.XXX.XX:XXXX/command.htm?number=123456`
my phone is immediatly starting the call.

the skript is within a CRM software. if i klick on the telephone number of my client the skript will be activated but nothing happens...